# Запятая перед «и» в перечислении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, перечисление

*Твоё сознание ограничено информацией из газет, радио и телевидения(,) и житейскими представлениями*.

Ставим ли мы тут запятую перед "и"? Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступно эта тема рассмотрена в ПАС:

> Примечание. В предложениях с однородными членами возможно употребление одних и тех же союзов на разном основании (между разными членами предложения или их группами). В таком случае при расстановке знаков препинания учитываются разные позиции союзов. Например: *...Везде ее встречали весело **и** дружелюбно **и** уверяли ее, что она хорошая, милая, редкая* (Ч.) — в этом предложении союзы ***и*** не повторяющиеся, а одиночные, соединяющие пары двух однородных членов предложения *(весело и дружелюбно; встречали и уверяли*)...

Указанная запятая не нужна:
*Твоё сознание ограничено информацией из газет, радио и телевидения и житейскими представлениями.*
Разбираем, задаем вопросы:
информацией (из чего? Р. п.) из газет, радио и телевидения (однородные дополнения);
ограничено (чем? Т. п.) информацией и представлениями (другая группа дополнений).

Вот, как мне кажется, интереснейший пример с тремя группами однородных членов, где перед "и" запятые не ставятся ([Давид Самойлов. Снегопад](https://imwerden.de/pdf/samoylov_vest_1978__ocr.pdf)).

*Он тёк, как легкий ровный душ,

Без звука **и** без напряженья

**И** тысячам усталых душ

Дарил покой **и** утешенье.*

[Он тёк и дарил; тёк без звука и без напряженья; дарил покой и утешенье.]

[Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения с союзами и без союзов](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не ставится, потому что структура следующая:
*Твоё сознание ограничено {информацией из газет, радио и телевидения} и {житейскими представлениями}.*
Первый союз И соединяет "радио" и "телевидение", а второй — "информацию" и "представления". "Телевидение" и "представления" союз по смыслу не соединяет, хоть и находятся они рядом, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Когда ряд однородных заканчивается, то запятая после последнего члена не ставится, если для этого нету причин, которые не связанны с однородными — например, если после однородных следует союз ‟ а ”, который требует перед собой запятую. В предложении: ‟ Клен, тополь, акация приветливо зеленели во дворе ” — после слова ‟акация” запятая не ставится. Точно так же и после слова ‟ телевидение ” в вашем предложении запятая не ставится. После этих однородных следует сочетание ‟и житейскими проблемами”, которое является однородным со словом ‟ информацией ”; тут запятая не ставится по правилу отсутствия запятой между однородными членами, соединенными союзом ‟ и ”.